# Перестала работать валидация данных

Tags: node.js, multer, express-validator

Перестала работать валидация данных, я использую [express-validator](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator) и [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). `express-validator` я проверяю поля введеные пользователем, `multer` загружает и проверяет изображения. Почитав документацию я увидел что `Multer добавляет объект body и объект file (или files) внутрь объекта request. Объект body содержит значения текстовых полей формы, объект file (files) содержит файл или файлы, загружаемые через форму.`. Теперь вопрос как проверять `express-validator` поля введеные пользователем когда `multer` добавляет объект body внутрь объекта `request`?

Делаю так:

```
import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator/check';

const validatorSignup = [
    check('user_name').exists().isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 }),
    ....
];

router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    try {
        upload(req, res, validatorSignup, (err) => {
            console.log(req.body)
            const errors = validationResult(req.body);
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    err: errors.array()
                });
            }
      ....
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            err: err
        });
    }
});
```

В `validationResult` передаю `req.body`, все работает, но если одно или более поле оставляешь пустым, `express-validator` не реагирует на это.

Так же попытался передать в `upload` сам массив `validatorSignup` но получил ошибку

```
onFinished(req, function () { next(err) })
                                    ^
TypeError: next is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multer` должен идти перед валидации полей, т.к. именно он декодирует `multipart/form-data` данные. Так:

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    try {
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            console.log(req.body)
            const errors = validationResult(req.body);
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    err: errors.array()
                });
            }
      ....
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            err: err
        });
    }
}, validatorSignup);
```

Comment: Можно по подробнее?

Comment: Просто сначала в чейне `upload` поставьте, а потом уже `validatorSignup`.

Comment: То есть так `upload(req, res, validatorSignup, (err) => {`?

Comment: @MegaRoks обновил ответ.

Comment: К сажалению он так же не проверяет, пользователь зарегистрировался с пустым майлом

Comment: @MegaRoks а вы данные точно мультипартом добавляете?

Comment: Да, в `postman` вкладка `form-data`. C провркой изображения проблем нет